# How do i order my datatable column to display in ascending order

Tags: javascript, json, datatable

I have this section of code already in place and i think it uses the domsourced method to render the control with the class `.file-upload table` as a datatable.

```
initDataTable = function () {
        services.dataTables.domSourced('.file-upload table');
      };
```

now i want to use this code below to order the first column in desc order, how do i do that

```
"order": [[0, 'asc']],
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```